# disable tkinter keyboard shortcut

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an event handler that I bound to <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>, which Tkinter also recognizes as <kbd>backspace</kbd>.
Though I read that with a `return 'break'` at the end of the handler I should stop the propagation of the shortcut, it doesnt work!
Is it a <kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd> problem, or what?

Here's the code:

```
def setheading(event=None):
    x=tkSimpleDialog.askstring('Set as header line', 'Enter an integer 1-5: ')
    config.text.tag_add('h'+x, SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
    return 'break'
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where is control-h acting incorrectly? In the widget where the binding is, in a widget inside the dialog, or somewhere els? Be more specific, and try to include a complete working example. There are a myriad of ways to handle bindings so we need as many details as you cn give.

Comment: everything happens in a Text widget (name: config.text). Here ctrl-h in fact runs setheading(), but at the same time backspaces over the last character before INSERT

Comment: Also look at this commit to see how I solved it in my project https://github.com/GrosSacASac/WebSpree/commit/40bf9da7346397f31767febe3872aba125cfbd42

Answer (score 1):

You probably bound CTRL+H on the root.

The reason this happens is because the event is dispatched in this order :

1. Widget callback
2. Widget class callback *
3. Root callback

   *(this is where the default behavior comes from)

The solution is to bind the event twice. Once on the Text widget itself with `return "break"` and once on the root so that the callback is triggered with other widgets as well. The `return "break"` on the widget will prevent it to go to phase 2 (the next), where the undesired default behavior comes from.

You can use an utility like this one

```
def k(handler):
    """decorates an event handler in such a way
that the default shortcut command is not triggered
same as event.preventDefault() in HTML5 but
as a decorator"""
    def prevent_default(*event):
        handler(event)
        return 'break'
    return prevent_default
```

related answer for more details about callback cascading [disable tkinter keyboard shortcut (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813219/disable-tkinter-keyboard-shortcut-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the statement `config.text.tag_add(...)` is throwing an error that is not being caught. If that's the case the return statement will never execute. If the return never executes, there's nothing to prevent the class bindings from firing.

The error will be thrown if no text is selected in the window.