# disable tkinter keyboard shortcut (2)

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm proposing a continuation of the discussion in [disable tkinter keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675522/disable-tkinter-keyboard-shortcut): I have an event handler for an event that Tkinter also uses, so that my prog & Tkinter interact badly.

Since it is a problem that I've been unable to solve I'm re-proposing here, where I tried to boil it down to the simplest form in the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

def init():
    global root,text

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500+0+0")
    dFont=tkFont.Font(family="Arial", size=10)

    text=Text(root, width=16, height=5, font=dFont)
    text.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand = YES)

    root.bind("<Control-b>", setbold)

    text.tag_config("b",font=('Verdana', '10', 'bold' ))
    text.tag_config("i",font=('Verdana', '10', 'italic' ))

def removeformat(event=None):
    text.tag_remove('b',SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
    text.tag_remove('i',SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)

def setbold(event=None):
    removeformat()
    text.tag_add('b', SEL_FIRST,SEL_LAST)
    text.edit_modified(True)

def main():
    init()        
    mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What it should do is simply to produce a text window where you write into.
Selecting some text and pressing <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> the program should remove any preexisting tag, then assign to it the 'b' tag that sets the text to bold.

What instead happens is an exception at the first `tag_remove`, telling me that `text doesn't contain any characters tagged with "sel"`.

The suggestion to use a `return 'break'` is of no use, since the selection disappears before `setbold()` has any chance to act...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your binding on the text widget, not on the root. (Whole toplevel bindings are processed *after* widget class bindings – where the standard `<Control-Key-b>` binding is – and those are processed *after* the widget instance bindings, which is what you want to use here.) And you need to do that `'break'`; it inhibits the subsequent bindings. (If you're having any problems after that, it's probably that the focus is wrong by default, but that's easy to fix.)

The only other alternative is to reconfigure the bindtags so that class bindings are processed after toplevel bindings, but the consequences of doing that are very subtle and far-reaching; you should use the simpler approach from my first paragraph instead as that's the normal way of handling these things.

Comment: To be clear, the standard order of binding groups for non-toplevels is this: widget instance, widget class, toplevel instance, global. (For toplevels the widget instance _is_ the toplevel instance, which can cause problems if you're not expecting it.) This order can be changed with bindtags, with new groups inserted and old groups removed; this is a very advanced technique, fun to play around with but not something to use in production code until you've exhausted all simpler alternatives.

Comment: Yes, That Was IT ! Now - if you're willing to advice me a bit further... I still have the surprising fact that Ctrl-1 ... Ctrl-5 are un-bindable, i.e. whatever I try the event isnt triggered! Instead - surprising - from Ctrl-6 to Ctrl-9 it works. Any idea???

Answer (score 3):

Bindings are handled in a specific order, defined by the `bindtags` of that widget. By default this order is:

1. The specific widget
2. The widget class
3. The toplevel window
4. The special class "all"

If there are conflicting bindings -- for example, a control-b binding on both the widget and class -- they both will fire (in the described order) unless you break the chain by returning `"break"`.

In the case of the code you posted, however, you are binding to the toplevel window (ie: the root window), and the conflicting binding is on the class. Therefore, the binding will fire for the class before it is processed by the toplevel, so even if your binding returned `"break"` it wouldn't matter since the class binding happens first.

The most straight-forward solution is to move your binding to the actual widget and return `"break"`. That will guarantee your binding fires first, and the `return "break"` guarantees that the class binding does not fire.

If you really want  your binding on the root window, you can remove the binding for the class using the `bind_class` method with the value of `"Text"` for the class.

You might find the [Events and Bindings](http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/events-and-bindings.htm) page on effbot.org to be useful.